# VS code theme | change color if function type is any

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

**VsCode Default Dark Them**

When a function exist, the color is yellow

[image]

And its white when the functin is of type any

[image]

**Using a custom theme (SynthWave '84)**

Color stays the same in both case

[image]
[image]

How do I do it that the custom theme shows white color if the function is of type Any

Comment: Look up the term "semantic syntax highlighting" and see how that is implemented to learn how to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this code to your `setting.json`:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

        "[your theme name]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "meta.function-call",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#ffffff"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: I tried but doesnt work :(

Comment: Did you replace `your theme name` in the code with your [own theme name](https://imgur.com/a/w84kefm). This setting [worked on my machine](https://imgur.com/a/WKzmpq7).